# SharePoint: Can’t display custom column value in Search Results

Tags: column, crawling, property, managed

Good Day!
I have the List on SharePoint Site. It’s enabled for showing in search results. I see its elements in Search Results Page.
I would like to show my custom column values in Search Results. The column name is “FTP_Path”. Type is single line text
1.  I looked this article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/search/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-search-resultsoption-1
2.  I created Management Property named FTPPath with Search ability enabled. I added the crawled property ows_FTP_Path as mapped crawled property
3.  I go to the Site Setting -> Master Page Gallery -> Display Templates/Search and locate the Item_Default.html file
4.  Copy the Item_Default file and rename it to Item_Copy
5.  Open the file in a text editor and find the title tag. Change the title to TEST.
6.  At the end of ManagedPropertyMapping tag I added 
,'FTP_Path':'FTPPath'
7.  Updated Table tag as follows

```
            <table>

                    <tr>
                                                                                    <!—Some Another Item Properties -->
                            </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td class="ftp">
                    _#=ctx.CurrentItem.FTP_Path=#_
                    </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
```

8. I told SharePoint to use my new Item_Copy template. It is working fine.

And I can’t see FTP_Path column values in Search results…

When I look my search results page by FireBug, I see that td tag with “ftp” class is empty on the page.

I looked this article https://www.eliostruyf.com/making-columns-searchable-for-the-list-or-library-searchbox/
 and can’t understand, what is wrong. 
Full content crawling didn’t help.
I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a **new result type** to get custom managed properties in search results and then click update result type.
Go to **Site settings --> Search Result Types** and copy the SharePoint List Item.

See this blog by Bella Engen
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/09/06/how-to-create-a-new-result-type-in-sharepoint-server-2013/

Answer (score 0):

While creating the new managed property you need to check the **Retrievable** property of it to enable the Column to appear in Search results.

[image]

And do not forget to do a full crawl after a new managed property is created/modified.

Then add the managed property in the mapping in the display template like

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Title':'Title','<Current item property name>':'<Managed property name>'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
```

So in your case it will be

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Title':'Title','FTP_Path':'ows_FTP_Path'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
```

Then you can fetch the column in the search results like you have mentioned

```
_#=ctx.CurrentItem.FTP_Path=#_
```

Hope that helps..

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much! I found my error.

I updated the string in my Item_Copy template

```
_#=ctx.CurrentItem.FTP_Path=#_
```

to

```
 _#=ctx.CurrentItem.FTPPath=#_
```

And it is working!